# Nextcloud 12 giving me an issue with X-Frame-Options

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, nextcloud

Fresh install of Nextcloud 12 on Centos 7 using apache. I haven't configured anything yet but I keep getting the following error codes on the admin console:

`X-Frame-Options" HTTP header is not configured to equal to "SAMEORIGIN`

`X-Content-Type-Options" HTTP header is not configured to equal to "nosniff`

I've looked at the .htaccess file and I have both of those set, but when I restart Apache the error persists.

```
 <IfModule mod_env.c>
# Add security and privacy related headers
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
Header set X-Download-Options "noopen"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey looks like apache is not reading the .htaccess file this is usually fixed by the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

After the section ends<Directory "/var/www/html"> </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud>
AllowOverride ALL
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[Here is a full install guide of nextcloud on centos 7](https://blog.krusesec.com/install-nextcloud-13-0-5-on-centos-7/)